# RequireJS node custom module issues - undefined parameter passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, undefined, requirejs

Node output running the code shown below is:

```
all Loaded
dbModule undefined
mongoose loaded
```

I have trouble getting a reference to dbMod2 in appMod2.  What should I try?

```
//server.js
var requirejs = require( 'requirejs');

process.on( 'uncaughtException', function(error) {
    console.log( 'Exception ' + error.stack);
    process.exit( 1);
});

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '.',
    nodeRequire: require
});

requirejs(['./appMod2'], function() {
    console.log( "all Loaded");
})

// appMod2.js
require(['./dbmod2'], function( dbmodule) {
    console.log( "dbModule " + dbmodule);
});

// dbmod2.js
require(['mongoose'], function( mongoose) {
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    console.log( "mongoose loaded");
});
```

Comment: It is unclear to me why you mix 'require' and 'requirejs'

Comment: Werner, I tried all combinations after reading different examples.  Consistency would have been better in the code.

Answer (score 0):

for replacing 'require' calls with 'define' and adding return statement to the modules:

```
// dbmod2.js
define(['mongoose'], function( mongoose) {
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    console.log( "mongoose loaded");

    return 'dbmod2';
});

// appMod2.js
define(['./dbmod2'], function( dbmodule) {
    console.log( "dbModule " + dbmodule);

    return 'appMod2';
});
```

I get this output:

```
mongoose loaded
dbModule dbmod2
all Loaded
```

in requirejs, the object passed to a the function following the dependency array is the object returned by the dependency